# Override inner class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, overriding

Lets have an example

```
class A:
    class B:
        def f(self):
            return 1
    def a(self):
        return A.B().f()
    def b(self):
        return self.B().f()

class C(A):
    class B(A.B):
        def f(self):
            return 2

print(A().a())
print(A().b())
print(C().a())
print(C().b())
```

will produce

```
1
1
1
2
```

I want to do something, that it produces

```
1
1
2
2
```

How can I override class A, so that both methods, a and b returns 2?
I am working with generated code with antlr. What I want to do, is for example to override __str__() methods to have some kind of better information. It keeps generating code like MyLanguageParser.RootContext() instead of self.RootContext(), and now, what I want to override anything I need to cope methods code, where classes are being called. 

Do you have any solutions? I know I am not the best with Python yet.

Maybe it is not possible and solution is to change generated code, but what I heard it is very bad idea. 
Edit:
Class A is generated and is immutable
What I have thought is something like

```
A.B = C.B
print(A().a())
print(A().b())
print(C().a())
print(C().b())
```

will generate

```
2
2
2
2
```

I do not know if it is legal. Actually I will not use A class, but rest of generated code can use it. I do not know if it is safe.
Edit 2: Corrected error with lack of self

Comment: You need to change how the code is generated, or override `a` and `b` instead of `B`.

Comment: lets say, that class A is generated and is immutable

Comment: That just means you change the things that control its generation, rather than editing the generated code directly.

Comment: Your first example doesn't work the way you claim it will because it is written improperly — all regular methods have at least one initial argument usually called `self`. Yours don't so, for example: `print(A().a())` -> `TypeError: a() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`. If class A was generated, it was done incorrectly.

Comment: @martineau Corrected that error, but it does not matter that match

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:

```
class A:
    class B:
        def f(self):
            return 1
    def a(self):
        # `type(self)` here instead of `A`
        # to get actual `C` class instead of `A`
        # when `a()` calls for `C()`
        return type(self).B().f()
    def b(self):
        return self.B().f()

class C(A):
    class B(A.B):
        def f(self):
            return 2
```

**Or** without modifing `A`:

```
class A:
    class B:
        def f(self):
            return 1
    def a(self):
        return A.B().f()
    def b(self):
        return self.B().f()


class C(A):
    class B(A.B):
        def f(self):
            return 2

    def a(self):  # reimplement
        return type(self).B().f()
```

**Or** somehow trying to rewrite `A` dynamically to avoid rewriting `a`'s code:

```
class A:
    class B:
        def f(self):
            return 1
    def a(self):
        return A.B().f()
    def b(self):
        return self.B().f()


class C(A):
    class B(A.B):
        def f(self):
            return 2

    def a(self):
        tmp, globals()['A'] = A, type(self)
        try:
            return super().a()
        finally:
            globals()['A'] = tmp
```

Note, this might be bad idea. I would think if there's better way.

Comment: I cannot change A like that, A is given. What I can do is change C or do sth like A.B = C.B, but it will produce 2 2 2 2 instead of 1 1 2 2

Comment: @MichałPiotrStankiewicz I updated answer. Can you override a() inside B?

Comment: Well rewriting is someting I want to avoid, if it is possible.

Comment: @MichałPiotrStankiewicz, I updated answer again, but, as noted, this might be bad idea. You can use it as hot fix, but I would prefer to find other way =\